# docker-compose and deployment

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker for development and have a docker-compose.yml file. Most services (php, httpd, node, python) have local mounts (volumes) for the project's files and configuration.

When I deploy my project, since those mount points are local, the files there will not exist on a remote host.

In that scenario what is the best approach to deploy my project? Are there guidelines or best practices I can follow?

Here is a partial of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:

php:
    build: ./src/docker/php/
    image: project-name/php
    expose:
        - 9000
    volumes:
        - ./httpd-api:/var/www
    working_dir: /var/www

httpd-api:
    image: httpd:2.4.29
    depends_on:
        - php
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    expose:
        - 80
    volumes:
        - ./httpd-api/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
        - ./httpd-api/httpd-vhosts.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
    volumes_from:
        - php

httpd-ng:
    image: httpd:2.4.29
    ports:
        - 80:80
    volumes:
        - ./httpd-ng/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
        - ./httpd-ng/html/.htaccess:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/.htaccess
        - ./angular/dist:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you have to update Docker image and you can add them using COPY statement to the desired mount-point.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

- You have to create Dockerfile in each of your project

  - then in individual Dockerfile COPY all the required files from context to the newly create Docker-image (docker-image-name  can be set through docker-compose.yml)
- Update your docker-compose.yml for build operations.

And then execute your project like --- docker-compose up --build

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: You need to create your own Dockerfile and have base image as "php" or "httpd" .

Comment: Share your docker-compose.yml file

Comment: For that I would need to:
1- change my docker-compose.yml to a 'deployment' version and include the COPY statements
2- docker commit the changes to the images
3- docker push the images to docker hub along with my files, is that right?
4- change the docker-compose.yml file to use the images I created in step 1

Comment: that is the correct answear, but now I have another problem. I need two sets of docker-compose.yml and Dockerfiles for development and deployment. any thoughts on how I can have a docker-compose.yml that works for development and deployment?

Comment: You can try with 2 docker-compose.yml (one for dev and one for deployment).. in DEV you can mount/volume your local src folder to the relevant folder in Docker image and in case of Deployment you can skip mounting/volume part.

Comment: Thank you fly2matrix. I found out there is a docker-compose.override.yml you can use and I got it working.